# Unix, Mac OS and Linux?

Tags: linux, osx, macintosh, unix-philosophy

I am working to learn more about unix and linux for a project. I noticed that Unix is the parent system of Mac OS and also of linux.

Are the two similar in scope of C based programming? And how closely do they relate to linux?

Comment: `b` came before `c` - C++ came after `C` but there are so many different languages Pascal, Fortran, Ada, Basic, ... I don't think you can think of them as an heirachy. I'm not sure if there was an `A` before `B` maybe that was Assembler (machine language).

Comment: Unix history is a lot more complex than that. Mac OS X and Linux are both Unix-like, neither are officially Unix.

Comment: @teppic Mac OS? Or Mac OS X? And are they the same thing?

Comment: Check out Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment  by Richard Stevens if you want to learn about this stuff within the framework of C.

Comment: @Hikari Mac OS before OS X had no relation to Unix. It was a very basic operating system.

Comment: @teppic Thank you, I'll be sure to research that as well :D I'm even more excited now since I just got so much useful and new info!

Comment: @teppic mac OS X *is* officially UNIX.

Comment: @casey It has the trademark? I knew it'd got POSIX certification but not Unix.

Comment: @teppic MacOS X 10.11 el capitan is certified UNIX 03.  The earlier versions of X are also certified.  http://www.opengroup.org/csq/search/t=XY1.html

Comment: @casey ok, didn't know that. Of course Unix is little more than a trademark these days, POSIX is what matters.

Comment: @Hikari do you want to learn C programming and you are asking on which OS will it be easy?

Comment: @teppic POSIX conformance is part of the requirements for UNIX certification.  I agree that POSIX is what matters, not the UNIX branding.  I was just pointing out that Mac OS X isn't unix-like.

Comment: @casey I'm not arguing with you, just pointing out that whether you're Unix or Unix-like (as with Linux and the BSDs) has very little relevance these days so long as you're POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix is not an OS but rather a family of OS. Mac OS is OS. Linux is not OS but a kernel

If you want to learn C programming it doesn't matter on which OS you use because all that matter is compiler. Different compiler will give you slightly different binary but for learning purpose they will all be almost same.

I recommend [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/index.html) or [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) for novice users learning C language
(my personal opinion: `clang` is recommended by experts because it is faster than `gcc` and its error reporting is better than `gcc`. [Difference](http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html#gcc) between `clang` and `gcc`)

Comment: Thanks @edwardtorvalds I'll be sure to give those a check.

Comment: There are loads of differences between OSes when it comes to C programming. Plus clang's certainly not better than gcc.

Comment: @teppic care to venture one? plus note I mentioned it for beginners they should concerntrate on C programming rather than on OS

Comment: Well, the question concerns Unix programming in C. For standard library stuff there's no real difference but all of the BSD/SysV/POSIX stuff varies.

Comment: @teppic well to me it means the OP wants to do C programming (or learning) so my answer. about which one is better its my personal opinion as mentioned

Comment: I think it isn't a bad idea to learn C in the context of Unix. After all that's what C was made for. In retrospect I think my understanding of, for example, what stdio does would have been much cleared had I learned it in the context of the raw system calls. Standards abstract the underlying implementation away, and it's common knowledge that learning is better done from the concrete toward the abstract.

Comment: @PSkocik but for learning purpose does it matters on which OS you learn? i dont think so

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X and Linux implement an interface between user programs and an OS kernel. This  interface started in Unix and got standardized in the so called POSIX* standard. **Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment** is a good book to read if you want to learn about this interface. Unix is more than just the implementation though. It's about a philosophy of developing software the summary of which can be found at http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html (it's part of a whole book available online).

(*The story of the standards is really a little bit more involved. The books provide more details).